# How to use a separate configuration file for tests in CI, using Play and sbt?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

For a project based on Play with sbt, I'd like to have multiple flavors for test runs, using different configuration files. Motivation is being able to run tests either against a local or a remote database.

There's already a custom config file speicified for general test runs (in build.sbt):

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

Now I would like to have another command where the same tests run against some configuration file `conf/application.test-ci.conf`.

### Approaches tried so far

#### Adding a command alias

```
addCommandAlias("test-ci", ";test -Dconfig.file=conf/application.test-ci.conf")
```

This fails with an error message of a missing semicolon (`;`), indicating that sbt interprets the resulting command line as multiple commands, but I don't understand why.

#### Extend `Test`

```
lazy val CITest = config("ci") extend Test

lazy val config = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
.configs(CITest)
.settings(inConfig(CITest)(Defaults.testTasks): _*)
.settings(
  javaOptions in CITest += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test-ci.conf"
)

javaOptions in CITest -= "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"
```

I'm don't fully understand what this is doing, but it always seems to pick up the other test configuration file.

**How can I specify multiple test setups picking up different configuration files?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first applying the setting via `set` command and then follow up with `test` task like so

```
addCommandAlias(
  "test-ci", 
  """;set Test/javaOptions ++= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.con"); test"""
)
```

Notice how `;` separates the `set` from `test`.

Comment: Nice, this seems to work! From what I understand, this now ends up with the config file being set twice, to different values (since that javaOption is already set for the main `test` command), right? The application seems to pick up the one here though, but I'm not sure if that's guaranteed.

Comment: I _think_ this can be made safer by prepend `;set Test/javaOptions --= Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf")` to the command, to remove the existing flag.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to modify the setting based on the environment. Usually there is some environment variable set on CI like `CI` or `BUILD`, so you can modify `javaOptions` conditionally (without any custom configurations):

```
Test/javaOptions ++= {
  if (sys.env.get("CI").isEmpty) Seq.empty
  else Seq("-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test-ci.conf")
}
```

Note: `Test/javaOptions` is the new syntax for `javaOptions in Test` (since sbt 1)